# How to run json_encode as a demo

Tags: json

How to get `json_encode` out like this demo.. I have tried many ways but can not figure out how to integrate `json_encode`. Can someone please help me?

```
{"ten":"Đế Vương Công Lược","ten-khac":"Đế Vương Công Lược","dao-dien":null,"dien-vien":null,"cover":"http://dll.anime47.com/imgur/IbX9uTR.jpg","alt-cover":null,"quoc-gia":null,"nam-san-xuat":"Đang cập nhật","noi-dung":"''Xuất thân từ hoàng tộc, Sở Uyên mỗi việc làm đều như đi một nước cờ - có thể nhìn như không có gì, nhưng có ảnh hưởng đến cả đại cục.\nĐăng cơ năm mười tám tuổi thì chưa tới nửa năm sau Vân Nam đã nổi loạn, mặc dù các lão thần đương triều mỗi người một tâm tư khác nhau nhưng đều muốn xem tân hoàng đế sẽ xử lý cục diện như thế nào. Cũng thật khó lường, tân đế ở vương thành còn chưa kịp tạo ra động tĩnh thì ngàn dặm ngoài kia, Tây Nam Vương Đoàn Bạch Nguyệt đã sớm tự xuất binh dẹp loạn, thế như chẻ tre, không quá nửa năm đã bình định giặc cỏ.\nNội cung lác đác ánh trăng, Sở Uyên tự tay đóng con dấu, hạ lệnh đưa mật hàm khẩn cấp tám trăm dặm tới Vân Nam – Lần này lại muốn trẫm dùng cái gì trao đổi?\nNét chữ cứng rắn thấm qua cả mặt sau giấy tuyên thành, hầu như có thể nhìn ra được lúc viết mấy chữ này, vị đế vương trẻ tuổi đã phẫn nộ ra sao.\nĐoàn Bạch Nguyệt thong thả mở giấy ra, đoan đoan chính chính trả lời một chữ.\nNgươi.''","list-ep":[{"ep-name":"01","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-01/153155.html\" class=\"active"},{"ep-name":"02","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-02/153165.html"},{"ep-name":"03","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-03/153293.html"},{"ep-name":"04","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-04/153417.html"},{"ep-name":"05","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-05/153514.html"},{"ep-name":"06","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-06/153614.html"},{"ep-name":"07","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-07/153746.html"},{"ep-name":"08","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-08/154058.html"},{"ep-name":"09","ep-link":"http://anime47.com/xem-phim-de-vuong-cong-luoc-ep-09/154234.html"}],"trang-thai":"09/??","the-loai":"Cartoon,","dang-anime":"TV Series","season":null}
```

`json_encode` it has two types

> list-ep":[

Answer (score 0):

define your array and put your data in array then json_encode  and echo.

```
$data= array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I tried but did not know how to make it run like a demo.